# Python Storage for matrix from opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am creating an face recognition software with python that matches faces to names with the help of labels.
I have a function that returns a list of image matrices   and another list of one dimensional labels . The idea is to save the two lists and make it possible to append the lists with a new image matrix and label.
I used json but the got unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' error. I am using pickle now but i cant append with new data
This is part of the save function using pickle

```
 with open("images.data","wb") as file:
    file.write(pickle.dumps({"faces":faces,"labels":labels}))
with open("images.data", 'rb') as f:
    new_data = pickle.load(f)
    faces=new_data.get('faces')
    print(faces[0])
    labels=new_data.get("labels")
return faces,labels
```

Below is one of the image matrix within the list and the label is just a list of numbers as I stated earlier

```
[[199 199 199 ... 213 214 214]
 [199 199 199 ... 213 214 214]
 [199 198 198 ... 213 213 213]
 ...
 [213 213 213 ... 232 232 232]
 [213 213 213 ... 232 232 232]
 [213 213 213 ... 232 232 232]]
```

So basically I am looking for suggestion because i have searched everywhere  to no avail

Comment: The attached code looks fine and runnable, what is the issue ?

Comment: the code works but what if i wanted to add new data to the existing one

Comment: Simply add new data after `pickle.load()` and then again serialize it using `pickle.dumps()`

Comment: that doesnt work though. i created `face=image matrix  and label=2` then used `open("images.data", 'rb')`  the new data removed and replaced the older ones

Comment: if `faces` and `labels` variables are of type `list` then you need to use `.append()` method to add new values to list. Using `face=image matrix and label=2` would simply replace the variables from `list` to a single value only.